# Single word equivalent for short, natural length grass?

Tags: single-word-requests, descriptive-grammar

I am trying to describe the length of grass in an area without dwelling on it too much with multiple adjectives or a more in depth explanation. The main point I am trying to get across is that the grass is not unkempt and out of control, but rather short in a natural way though not neat to the extent of a sporting field. It could have been mowed some time ago (depending on how fast it grows) or kept short by livestock. The reason doesn't matter as much it is only the final look that is relevant.

I have included an image as a rough illustration in the first image below, but the look could be slightly longer and less neat as well. I have looked through for landscaping/lawn maintenance terms that may be specific of grass lengths but wasn't able to find anything specific. I have also looked through different types of grass to see if maybe there is a specific one that is always recommended to keep at such a length, but again I've had little success. The only other idea I had was to use natural ecosystems to describe it, like "savanna length grass", which although of course savannas do not all have the same length grass everywhere, it does provide a concise, general idea of the look.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m confused.  You say “a concise general idea of the look” but I think of the bottom picture only. I assume you also want it to cover the unmown grass on the first picture as well. But that is not savanna-length at all.  And it’s not even natural-length.

Comment: You'll be glad to know your tall [**grass is high**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guFJDNP9j9s).

Comment: Yes since I'm aiming for a very simple description I am happy to go with an appearance something between the two images. I don't think there is a way to get around the vagueness without a more verbose and specific description?

Comment: @YosefBaskin "high grass" seems pretty common enough, although doing a search it appears the length of what is considered "high grass" can vary considerably. Happy for you to turn this into an answer though.

Comment: Image search *fieldgrass* and see if that resonates. [Example](https://pixabay.com/photos/landscape-field-grass-summer-2124952/).

Comment: If there is nothing unusual about the grass, the plain “grass” might work.

Answer (score -2):

"Turf" or "Short-Turf" might be suitable here...
"Tussock" might also work...

> Tussock: A small area of grass which is thicker and longer than the grass around it

[Tussock Meaning](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tussock)

Comment: Sources will help improve your answer.

Comment: This would work fine if you are in turf management; but otherwise, it is either doesn't bring an image to mind, or it defaults to a different set of ideas entirely.